# JS onclick of image populate form fields

Tags: javascript, html

Goal:  Click on the image and populate the form fields with applicable information for each item.  The form fields, and images, weren't a requirement but I thought that the images would be nice and populating a form seemed logical.  I guess I could onclick text and have an alert box pop up with the pertinent info but I have chosen this path.

Code:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Restaurant Menu</title>
    <link rel="styleheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css">
</head>
<body>

<h1>Restaurant Menu</h1>
<h3>Click on picture for details</h3>
<br>

<img src = "../Images/cheeseburger.jpg" alt = "cheeseburger" id = "cheeseburger" onclick = "cheeseFxn">
<br>
<br>

<img src = "../Images/pizza.jpg" alt = "pizza" id ="pizza" onclick = "pizzaFxn">
<br>
<br>

<img src = "../Images/hotdog.jpg" alt = "hotdog" id = "hotdog" onclick = "hotdogFxn">
<br>
<br>

<img src = "../Images/salad.jpg" alt = "salad" id= "salad" onclick = "saladFxn">


<form name = "details" id = "details">
    <p>Item Title</p>
    <input type = "text" name = "title" id = "title" size = "53" />
    <p>Item Description/List of Ingredients</p>
    <textarea name = "description" id = "description" rows = "5" cols = "40" ></textarea>
    <p>Price $</p>
    <input type = "text" name = "price" id = "price" size = "53"/>
</form>

<script>
    function cheeseFxn(cheeseburger)
    {
        var Title = document.getElementById("title").value = "cheeseburger";
        var Description = document.getElementById("description").value = "100% beef patty with cheese";
        var Price = document.getElementById("price").value = "$7.98";
    }
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: What's the issue you're having?

Comment: @tymeJV: I guess, JS function call's missing `()` so the function is not setting value of controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function was not being called because you are missing `()` with `onclick`. You need to put the function calling `()` with all controls. Like this:

```
 <img src = "../Images/cheeseburger.jpg" alt = "cheeseburger"
 id = "cheeseburger" onclick = "cheeseFxn()">
```

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Kujmp)**